# octomap_server globally referenced pointcloud and transform

Tags: octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to pass globally referenced point clouds and trajectories to octomap_server, but it's not producing the desired results? The point cloud and ray tracing are being inserted from the single origin of the first scan.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51837/octomap_server-globally-referenced-pointcloud-and-transform/) by [anonymousSnowMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3930/anonymoussnowman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the issue:

```
// directly transform to map frame:
pcl::transformPointCloud(pc, pc, sensorToWorld);
```

I believe this was performing a transform on already transformed trajectories. By commenting this entry out, rebuilding and trying again, the insertion and ray casting are working correctly.

---

Originally posted by [anonymousSnowMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3930/anonymoussnowman/) with karma: 38 on 2013-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the problem lies in your tf frames. octomap_server will transform your point clouds to the global map frame using TF, relying on the `frame_id` set in your sensor data. If you transformed them yourself but left the `frame_id` unchanged then it will transform it again. If you change the `frame_id` in the point cloud accordingly to the global map frame, octomap_server should not transform again.

However, the main problem I see is that octomap_server assumes single sensor readings  per cloud, each with its own origin, for its ray casting operation. It will cast a ray from the sensor origin to each end point. If you only have one origin, this will not result in a correct map since information behind intermediate obstacles may be missed, or existing obstacles cleared out.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2